# How to read the param tag values in NPAPI plugin?

Tags: npapi

I have developed a NPAPI plugin(npruntime) for windows browsers like firefox, safari, Google chrome.
My question is how one can read the values specified in the  tag of the  element in a plugin.

Is there any way to access these values in a plugin.? I searched a lot for this and unfortunately didn't get any help.
We can read the  tag attributes likes "type", "width" etc in NPP_New function.

Thanks in advance.

regards,
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

You get the  tags in the NPP_New function as well; they're all in the same place. Are you familiar with [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org)? It abstracts all of this for you and works on IE as well.

You can find the code that [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) uses to pull the params out here: https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/NpapiCore/NpapiPlugin.cpp#L76

(that function is called from NPP_New)